# CS1929 - List<T> does not contain an implementation of Where() (using System.Linq)

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Have been struggling to clear this compiler error for some time now.

> Compiler Error:  Line 29 - 'List newCollection =
> tempCollection.Where(predicate);'
>
> CS1929    'List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the
> best extension method overload
> 'ParallelEnumerable.Where(ParallelQuery, Func<T, bool>)'
> requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery'

As seen in the code snippet, I am attempting to call the extension method `Where()` from the Linq library with a predicate as the input arg. The collection I am trying to call this on is a `List<T>` - worth noting that I am trying to allow this new extension method `SnapFingers` to accept any `IEnumerable` of type `T`, I have a feeling this is where my issues are arising from. I understand being specific would probably fix this but I want to try to make it generic.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace BootCamp.Chapter
{
    public static class SnapFingersLINQ
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SnapFingers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate = null)
        {
            if (!items.Any())
            {
                return default(List<T>);
            }
            else
            {
                if (predicate != null)
                {
                    
                    IEnumerable<T> shuffItems = LINQExtensions.Shuffle(items);
                    List<T> tempCollection = shuffItems.ToList();

                    List<T> newCollection = tempCollection.Where<T>(predicate);

                    int numToRemove = AmountToRemove(items);
                    newCollection.RemoveRange(0, numToRemove);
                    
                    return tempCollection;
                }
                else
                {
                    List<T> shuffItems = LINQExtensions.Shuffle(items).ToList();
                    int numToRemove = AmountToRemove(items);
                    shuffItems.RemoveRange(0, numToRemove);
                    return shuffItems;
                }
            }
        }

        private static int AmountToRemove<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            int lengthCollection = items.Count();
            int numberOfElementsToRemove = lengthCollection / 2;
            if (lengthCollection % 2 == 0)
            {
                return numberOfElementsToRemove;
            }
            else
            {
                return numberOfElementsToRemove - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `LINQExtensions.Shuffle()` just returns a new shuffled collection, `IEnumerable<T>` (I am aware Linq Extension 'Shuffle' exists but this was a challenge as part of a bootcamp homework).

Any help on this would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Would you be able to expand please as I have done some digging but none of the information from MSDN or other posts seem to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther [`Where` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) expects a parameter of type `Func<T, bool>`, not `Predicate<T>`.

Change the signature of your method to:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SnapFingers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
```

..and then add a `ToList()` after the `Where` to avoid another compiler error:

```
List<T> newCollection = tempCollection.Where<T>(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great approach and seems to be that this is a 'better practice' approach than using the 'x => predicate.Invoke(x)' @Caleb Manning suggested, although both work the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update:
You should change the type of the second argument of the method `SnapFingers<T>` to `Func<T, bool> predicate` because the method `Where<T>` accepts that type rather than a `Predicate<T>`.

Original:

Try `List<T> newCollection = tempCollection.Where<T>(predicate).ToList();`

Explanation: the method `Where` of Linq returns `IEnumerable<T>`, you need to use `ToList` to turn it into a `List<T>`.

Comment: Just gave this a go and no change to the complier error. Am I trying to be too generic here maybe? Thank you tho!

Comment: @Equilibrium23 I have updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that `.Where` expects an argument of type `Func<T, bool>`. Try `List<T> newCollection = tempCollection.Where<T>(x => predicate.Invoke(x)).ToList();`

Comment: This has worked brilliantly thank you! I thought it couldn't of been that I hadn't been passing a function to it but this makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerable<T>.Where` method takes a `Func<T, bool>` not a `Predicate<T>`. Yes, they are essentially the same, but delegate types have distinct type identity, even if they are functionally the same.

Weirdly enough, I'm giving a *Lunch & Learn* session for.my extended team next week, and this is one of my examples

Comment: Thanks for this! Will be a great topic at your lunch and learn!